# how to recalculate display attribute after a hidden div is shown via javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-slider

I have a hidden div that has a bootstrap slider inside as follow:

```
<input id="concentration" type="text"
                        data-provide="slider"
                        data-slider-ticks="[0, 1, 2, 3]"
                        data-slider-ticks-labels='[" ", "pale", "medium", "deep"]'
                        data-slider-min="0"
                        data-slider-max="3"
                        data-slider-step="1"
                        data-slider-tooltip="hide"
                        data-slider-value="0"
                        />
```

When playing around with the website and clicking to show that div the display attribute does not calculate accordingly which cause the following problem:
[image]

when manually resizing the website the slider automatically recalculate the display attribute and shows fine:

[image]

how can I recalculate display attribute after a hidden div is shown via javascript:

```
$("#concentration_div").show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recalculate display attribute"?

Comment: I mean when I resize the window the div that was hidden does not take into account the new window display which causes the overlap

Comment: What is the display attribute set to before it's hidden?

Comment: I do not set it my self, I used the bootstrap-slider, I realized that when resizing the window the slider inside the hidden div does not load accordingly and cause the overlapping like shown in the pic

Comment: call `.slider('refresh')`

Comment: @Seiyria i tried already, that solution was proposed on GitHub but does not work for bootstrap slider inside a hidden div